# How to use bootstrap datepicker - jquery plugin in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker, angularjs-ng-model

I want to use this plugin in AngularJS in my export table with filters. 
is it possible to use it with ng-model and all other uses

the plugin :
https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

especially I need the "range" -from/to . option

Comment: Is is angular or angular js ?

Comment: use ui-bootstrap datepicker, if you are using angularJS

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap in combination with angularjs, I advise you to use UI-Bootstrap. These are AngularJS directives for bootstrap. It also has the bootstrap datepicker.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to combine AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421707/best-way-to-combine-angularjs-and-twitter-bootstrap).

Comment: UI-bootstarp date picker is not good enough case there is no option to do "range" option like in jquery

Answer (score 1):

To use [uxsolutions bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) in AngularJS, create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) like this:

```
app.directive("datepicker", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          elem.on("changeDate", updateModel);
          elem.datepicker({});

          function updateModel(event) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(event.date);
          }
      }
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
<div datepicker id="myDatePicker" ng-model="myDate"></div>
<div> {{myDate | date }} </div>
```

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PxiZkXDFBdrjEy51zM65?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("datepicker", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
          require: "ngModel",
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            elem.on("changeDate", updateModel);
            function updateModel(event) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(event.date);
            }
            elem.datepicker({});
          }
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div>Selected date: {{myDate | date}}</div>
    <div datepicker ng-model="myDate"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Can I use the ng-model also in the controller ? 
why do I need ngModel

Comment: `ng-model` is used for two way data binding. To get the ng-model value in controller we use `$scope` . For example if you want to get value `myDate` from above example you will use `$scope.myDate`  in controller.