# Angular UI, Bootstrap Navbar Collapse and Javascript

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have trouble with UI-Router in many ways. I don't understand how it interacts with other frameworks.

Namely, I am trying to implement Bootstrap 3's navbar collapse module, seen below:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is straight from the Bootstrap website and it works fine when inside its own .html page.

The issue is when I insert it into a UI-Router view. The collapsing action no longer works -- I'm guessing because the "data-target" function is somehow unable to find its target.

How does one use Bootstrap 3 with Angular UI? The Angular UI Bootstrap package does not have a navbar module.

The answer below is good. Here is a reference URL [Twitter Bootstrap Navbar with AngularJS - Collapse Not Functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741988/twitter-boostrap-navbar-with-angular-js-collapse-not-functioning?rq=1).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should replace bootstrap native js properties with ui-bootstrap directives (note the `ng-click` and `collapse`):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <!-- your branding here -->
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="navbarCollapsed">
      <!-- your normal collapsable content here -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Set the initial value in your controller:

```
$scope.navbarCollapsed = true;
```

**Edit:**

New versions of ui-bootstrap [prefix all compontents](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes). Adjust your code accordingly eg. `collapse` -> `uib-collapse`.

Comment: Could you explain to me what's happening in the backend which requires this? Is Ui-router overriding bootstrap.js's functions?

Comment: Actually ui-router has nothing to do with this. You need to include ui-bootstrap in your project if you didn't already. You do _not_ need any js files from the original twitter bootstrap distribution at all - they can be replaced by pure angular directives from ui-bootstrap.

Comment: Ok then what is causing the bootstrap.js to no longer function and need UI-bootstrap? Is it Angular itself?

Comment: By the way, this does work except the controller needs to be added to a surrounding Div.

Comment: My previous question is about what's happening under the hood not a preference.

Comment: It may be a little more readable to set the navbarCollapsed on the element, rather than in the controller.  You can add ... ng-init="navbarCollapsed=true" ... to the collapse <button>.

Comment: Also, adding `ng-click="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed"` to the links inside the `<div class="collapse...>` will auto-close the menu when a choice is made.

Comment: In ui-bootstrap 0.12.0 dropdown's in navbar are broken. 0.11.0 works fine.

Comment: @GrantLindsay i can't get ng-click to fire on any of the links in my bootstrap-ui navbar.  i'm using ui-sref, could this be why?  you can see my code running at http://oscil.io

Comment: also, i have tried adding `ng-click="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed"` to either of the `<li>` and `<a>` elements inside my `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` element, but to no avail.

Comment: @dcunited001 Can you post a minimal, working subset of your code to Plunkr or JSFiddle?

Comment: I have this, and the _button_ works, but, as opposed to bootstrap's "way", it won't *auto* collapse because the flag won't let it!

Comment: Seems that to the links inside the <div class="collapse" ...> not only we need to add ng-click="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed;" But also "$state.go ('state_name');" to go that state, otherwise the menu collapses without going to the state.

Comment: Nice and elegant solution!

Comment: With latest version of ui-boostrap (1.1.1) you need to use 'uib-collapse' instead of 'collapse'.  `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse" uib-collapse="navbarCollapsed">` See [ui-bootstap docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse).

Comment: @christophersw thanks for pointing this out! Added a short note about it.

Answer (score 2):

My particular issue revolved around scope. I'm using `ng-repeat` to loop through my menu items so `navbarCollapsed` wasn't accessable in the `ng-repeat` child scope.

The resolution was to access the parent scope's variables. Simple as:

```
ng-click="$parent.navbarCollapsed = !$parent.navbarCollapsed"
```

Hope this helps anybody having the same issue.