# Toggle/Hide Bootstrap Navbar Collapse on View Change with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap ui-module and AngularJS. My problem is on the mobile view, when a user changes views, the `.navbar-collapse` stays open and I want it to collapse when the view changes. I'm a noob to angular and I just found out about the bootstrap navbar directives, but here's what I am currently using:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" ng-click="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
          <a ng-click="nav.setActive('home'); gotoTop()" href="#/home">
            <div class="sprite sprite-logo">
              <span class="sr-only">Home Button</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-click="nav.setActive('home'); gotoTop()" href="#/home" class="navbar-brand">
            <div id="headerName">
              <h1 id="small-line">
                More Than 80 Years of Service
              </h1>
              <h1 id="big-line">
                BCOAPO
              </h1>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- end navbar-header -->
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar-collapse" collapse="navbarCollapsed">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="hidden-sm" ng-class="{ active:nav.isActive('home') }">
          <a ng-click="nav.setActive('home'); gotoTop()" href="#/home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> &nbsp;Home <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-leanpub"></i> &nbsp;About Us <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li ng-class="{ active:nav.isActive('about') }">
              <a ng-click="nav.setActive('about'); gotoTop()" href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> &nbsp;Who We Are</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active:nav.isActive('scholarships') }">
              <a ng-click="nav.setActive('scholarships'); gotoTop()" href="#/scholarships"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> &nbsp;Scholarships</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li ng-class="{ active:nav.isActive('branches') }">
          <a ng-click="nav.setActive('branches'); gotoTop()" href="#/branches"><i class="fa fa-building"></i> &nbsp;Branches</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active:nav.isActive('contact') }">
          <a ng-click="nav.setActive('contact'); gotoTop()" href="#/contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span> &nbsp;Contact Us</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- end main-navbar-collapse -->

  </div><!-- end container -->
  <div id="main-navbar-bumper"></div>
</nav>
```

JS

```
angular.module('BCOAPO').controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

  $scope.gotoTop = function() {
    $location.hash('top');

    $anchorScroll();
  };

  this.active;

  this.setActive = function(newActive) {
    this.active = newActive;
    return true;
  };

  this.isActive = function(currentActive) {
    if (this.active === currentActive) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  this.closeNav = function() {
    $('#main-navbar-collapse').hide();
    return true;
  };

  $scope.navbarCollapsed = true;

}]);
```

What I've Tried:

Using the directives `ng-click="navbarCollapsed = !navbarCollapsed"` and `collapse="navbarCollapsed"` as per [Angular UI, Bootstrap Navbar Collapse and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834507/angular-ui-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-and-javascript)

Creating a jQuery event to hide the navbar-collapse as per the `this.closeNav` function in my controller. But this caused the navbar to become permanently hidden. Is there a way to simply mimic the click event on the navigation links and apply it to the toggle button instead but only on screens less than 992px?

```
this.closeNav = function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle').click();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how i went about it.. I reverted back to the default bootstrap navbar without the angular directives and altered this function

```
$scope.gotoTop = function() {
  $location.hash('top');
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $('.navbar-toggle').click();
  }
  $anchorScroll();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
    $scope.gotoTop = function() {
$location.hash('top');
$scope.navbarCollapsed = false;
$anchorScroll();
```

};

or watch the state change?

```
  $scope.stateChange = $state;
   $scope.$watch('statechange.current.name',function(){
   $scope.navbarCollapsed = false;
   }
```

hope it helps

Comment: hrmm, okay I was able to get your first function to work by using `$scope.navbarCollapsed = !$scope.navbarCollapsed` but I am having other issues when using the bootstrap directives for the navbar. i've updated my answer to show the html to include the bootstrap directives. The navbar works, except there is now a margin that gets applied during the animation and the desktop view messes up when clicking any of the links.

Comment: have you tested it on different browsers? because sometimes bootstrap can act weird, on different browsers, also if its possible to put a snapshot of the margin error?

Comment: here's a snapshot of the bug, http://4.1m.yt/TaRgS4D9v.png when the navbar collapse open or closes, it looks like 20px of margin appear on the right side.. you can test it out here: http://cisweb.ufv.ca/~300105626/bcoapo2/

Comment: if you mean, from the yellow button? then do some margin-bottom in minus for the button and the logo or what you can do is, for the nav: do a margin-left:xx and margin-top: from the css, that might help you, but still the logo might stop it from getting very close to the yellow button, or you might want to decrease the size of the logo aswell when you