# Navbar didnt collapse with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap.css with Angular. I referenced [Twitter Bootstrap Navbar with AngularJS - Collapse Not Functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741988/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-with-angular-js-collapse-not-functioning) but when I try to implement this code, my navbar doesn't collapse and the dropdown doesn't work either.

**Code:**

```
<nav id="navbar-example" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static" role="navigation" ng-controller="NavBarCtrl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse bs-js-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a id="drop1" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://twitter.com/fat">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function NavBarCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
}
```

Why won't it collapse? Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vandivicario/1L4mtksk/).

Comment: are you sure you added angular js script ? its not present in jsfiddle..
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js">

Comment: on my external resources i include bootstrap.min css, angular.js, ui-bootstrap-tpls.js sir

Comment: did you use `ng-app` ?? also, bootstrap requires `jquery` for some functions like collapse.
please post full code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the developer tool? It is showing

```
https://fiddle.jshell.net/code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Because angular wasn't able to load hence angular bootstrap is not able to initial as well.

So please try to add another angular cdn and test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the class `show` on this part

```
 <div ng-class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'show':!isCollapsed}">
```