# Bootstrap4 menu toggle collapse is not working in AngularJs 1.x

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Navbar toggle menu is opening but not closing.

I have tried all the ways given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741988/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-with-angularjs-collapse-not-functioning) and others also to rectify this bug. But doesn't help me.
My code as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fix nav-color imgbg">
    <a class="navbar-brand red" href="#">Logo Title</a>
    <button 
            class="navbar-toggler" 
            type="button" 
            data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#navbarNav" 
            aria-controls="navbarNav" 
            aria-expanded="true" 
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav" ng-controller="HeaderController">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/home') }">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#!/home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about') }">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#!/about">Objectives</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contact') }">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#!/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the libs in order works for me:

my order as follows:

in head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
```

in end/bottom of body:

```
    <script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/shared/navbar.js"></script>
```